# Piccolo zoomable interface, how to change text when zooming

Tags: java, piccolo

I'm experimenting with some Piccolo to create a zoomable interface.

I'm creating a rectangle on a canvas with some PText on it. Now when zooming, I want to change the text to something different.

I've done this in my initialize:

```
//
        //specify the current Piccolo PCanvas
        //
        m_canvas = getCanvas();
        m_canvas.removeInputEventListener(m_canvas.getPanEventHandler());
        //m_canvas.addInputEventListener(new ClickAndDragHandler(m_canvas));

        //
        //add nodes to the collection -> adding to the collection = adding to the canvas
        //
        m_nodecollection = new NodeCollection(m_canvas);

        RectangleNode node_links = new RectangleNode();
        node_links.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);
        m_nodecollection.addNode(node_links);

        RectangleNode node_rechts = new RectangleNode();
        node_rechts.setBounds(600,10,500,500);
        m_nodecollection.addNode(node_rechts);

        PImage node_arrowLeft = new PImage("left.gif");
        node_arrowLeft.setBounds(600, 550, node_arrowLeft.getWidth(), node_arrowLeft.getHeight());
        m_nodecollection.addNode(node_arrowLeft);

        PImage node_arrowRight = new PImage("right.gif");
        node_arrowRight.setBounds(680, 550, node_arrowRight.getWidth(), node_arrowRight.getHeight());
        m_nodecollection.addNode(node_arrowRight);

        m_nodecollection.connectNodesWithLine(node_rechts, node_arrowRight, true);
        m_nodecollection.connectNodesWithLine(node_rechts, node_arrowLeft, true);


        PText node_text = new PText("Zoomlevel Not Supported");
        node_text.setBounds(180,150, node_text.getWidth(), node_text.getHeight());
        m_nodecollection.connectNodesWithLine(node_links, node_text, true);
        m_nodecollection.addNode(node_text);
        node_links.addChild(node_text);
        node_links.setCollection(m_nodecollection);
```

Created my own rectangle class with the whole nodecollection and PText as membervar.

```
public class RectangleNode extends PNode{

    private Rectangle2D m_rectangle;
    private NodeCollection collection;
private PText text;

    public RectangleNode()
    {
        m_rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    }

    public Rectangle2D getRectangle()
    {
        if(m_rectangle == null)
            m_rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        return m_rectangle;
    }

    public boolean setBounds(double x, double y, double w, double h)
    {
        if(super.setBounds(x, y, w, h))
        {
            m_rectangle.setFrame(x, y, w, h);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setCollection(NodeCollection collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
    }
        public void setText(PText text)
{
    this.text = text;
}
    public void paint(PPaintContext paintcontext)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = paintcontext.getGraphics();

        //niet ingezoomd
        if(paintcontext.getScale() <= 0.2)
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        //half ingezoomd
        if(paintcontext.getScale() > 0.2 && paintcontext.getScale() < 0.7)
        {

            g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        }

        //volledig ingezoomd
        if(paintcontext.getScale() > 0.7)
        {
            g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(getRectangle());
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
            g2.draw(getRectangle());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I thought I could change the text like this: text.setText("Tester"); but It doesn't work, also when for example settext and then add the node to collection then it displays over the current text with a huge error...

Can someone help me please?

kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider posting the whole example as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), looks like some parts of the code are missing. It is not clear how you actually execute `setText`.

It may be easier to compose existing nodes and listen to events fired from camera. Consider the following example that draws a rectangle with some text which gets updated according to a zoom level:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.PCamera;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PPath;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PText;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.util.PPaintContext;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolox.PFrame;

public class TestRectZoom extends PFrame {
    public TestRectZoom() {
        super("TestRectZoom", false, null);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        getCanvas().setInteractingRenderQuality(
                PPaintContext.HIGH_QUALITY_RENDERING);
        getCanvas().setDefaultRenderQuality(
                PPaintContext.HIGH_QUALITY_RENDERING);
        getCanvas().setAnimatingRenderQuality(
                PPaintContext.HIGH_QUALITY_RENDERING);

        final PPath rect = PPath.createRectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
        rect.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
        getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(rect);

        final PText text = new PText(getZoomLevelString());
        rect.addChild(text);

        text.centerFullBoundsOnPoint(rect.getBounds().getCenterX(), rect
                .getBounds().getCenterY());

        getCanvas().getCamera().addPropertyChangeListener(
                PCamera.PROPERTY_VIEW_TRANSFORM, new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        text.setText(getZoomLevelString());

                        if (getCanvas().getCamera().getViewScale() > 0.9) {
                            rect.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
                        } else {
                            rect.setPaint(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private String getZoomLevelString() {
        return "Zoom level:"
                + String.format("%.2f", getCanvas().getCamera().getViewScale());
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new TestRectZoom();
    }
}
```

That's how the result looks like:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for semantic zooming available on the Piccolo Patterns page. 
Pattern 17: Semantic Zooming

http://www.piccolo2d.org/learn/patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like Aqua suggested.